# Swift I can't convert html tag to string

Tags: swift

I create some web-service that pull html tag here my result.

```
<CurrentOilPriceResult><PTT_DS>
  <DataAccess>
    <PRICE_DATE>2016-01-09T05:00:00+07:00</PRICE_DATE>
    <PRODUCT>Blue Gasoline 95</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE>30.46</PRICE>
  </DataAccess>
  <DataAccess>
    <PRICE_DATE>2015-06-05T05:00:00+07:00</PRICE_DATE>
    <PRODUCT>Blue Gasoline 91</PRODUCT>
  </DataAccess>
  <DataAccess>
    <PRICE_DATE>2016-01-14T05:00:00+07:00</PRICE_DATE>
    <PRODUCT>Blue Diesel</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE>19.69</PRICE>
  </DataAccess>
  <DataAccess>
    <PRICE_DATE>2016-01-09T05:00:00+07:00</PRICE_DATE>
    <PRODUCT>Blue Gasohol 91</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE>23.08</PRICE>
  </DataAccess>
</PTT_DS></CurrentOilPriceResult></CurrentOilPriceResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I want to pull pain-text from html tag, is there any possible solution?

Comment: That's not HTML but XML. And you need to use an XML parser. Google is friend.

Answer (score 1):

The NSXMLParser can extract any information from XML data. Here's an example showing where the text arrives. I'm reading from a file here but you can get the XML from any stream.

```
import Foundation
class MyXmlDelegate : NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String){
        // CDATA content arrives here
    }
}
var delegate = MyXmlDelegate()
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file", withExtension: "xml")
let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url!)
xmlParser!.delegate = delegate
xmlParser!.parse()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I think because my XML is string value type. :(

Comment: Read the documentation on NSXMLParser. It accepts NSData too.